# Is there a more secure way to pass variables to a docker container than via env

Tags: security, docker, env

I'm experimenting with docker containers. More precise, I use `docker-compose`. I need to pass variables to my container and use an `.env` file for that. While that works, it makes my wonder how secure it is. I mean every script language has access to `env` and therefore any hack in the runnning application could expose sensitive data stored in env. I want to store data like db passwords.

Inspired by `salt`, I am looking for a way to safely pass my variables into my application template before building the container, instead of passing them into the `env` of the container. How could one achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an alternative using Docker Swarm called Docker secrets. A swarm allows you to have a cluster of docker engine nodes and you can create a one machine cluster if you wish. Basically you can use secrets that are stored in the Docker Swarm cluster that can be used when a service (a service will deploy tasks using containers in your cluster) is deployed in your cluster.

Docker secrets are explained [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/) and you can even use them in [your compose files](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#secrets). You have a nice example for your environment variables [here](https://medium.com/@basi/docker-environment-variables-expanded-from-secrets-8fa70617b3bc).

I use docker secrets to store Amazon S3 credentials that are used inside my containers.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I went with `args` for the current setup. This is practical enough for this dev-project. Your answer ultimately answers my question.

Answer (score 1):

nowadays you might [use docker-compose.yml and insert a secrets part](https://serverfault.com/questions/871090/how-to-use-docker-secrets-without-a-swarm-cluster?rq=1)

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.6"

services:

  my_service:
    image: ubuntu:latest
    entrypoint: "wc -c /run/secrets/my_secret"
    secrets:
      - my_secret

secrets:
  my_secret:
    file: ./password.txt
```

Answer (score -2):

Hashicorp Vault is the tool you are looking for. Store insensitive data in an .env, and for secrets use Vault.

https://www.vaultproject.io/